# Программа для подсчета букв на js

Tags: javascript

Добрый день!

JS

```
function countBs (x) {
  var count = 0;
  for (i=0; i<x.lenght ; i++) {
    if (x[i] === "B") {count += 1};
    };
  return count};
console.log(countBs("BfDbC"));
```

В консоли отображается 0, хотя в BfDbC присутствует одна B. Похоже, ошибка в i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опечатка - `length`, а не `lenght` :

```js
function countBs (x) {
  var count = 0;
  for (i=0; i<x.length ; i++) {
    if (x[i] === "B") {count += 1};
  };
  return count
};
console.log(countBs("BfDbC"));
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!